# How to stop cinemachine freelook camera rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I am working on a third person parkour game with new input system and cinemachine(Freelook). You move with the right joystick and look around using right joystick(Cinemachine Input provider). For doing tricks I am using button with one modifier, you press R2 and move the right joystick in different directions for different tricks. But when I move the right joystick for a trick cinemachine rotates the camera.

Is a way to stop cinemachine from rotating the camera when other buttons are pressed.

Thank you in advance, Hemanth

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable the component.

```cs
public CinemachineFreeLook freeLook;

private void Lock() => freeLook.enabled = false;
```

Another way is to set the Mouse Axis Speed to zero. In this method, with the help of a [**`tweener`**](http://dotween.demigiant.com/pro.php#:%7E:text=DOTween%20Pro%20is%20an%20extension,a%20small%20one%2Dtime%20fee.), you can gently disable the movement of the mouse.

```cs
private void Lock()
{
    DOVirtual.Float(freeLook.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed, 0f, 1f, value => freeLook.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = value);
    DOVirtual.Float(freeLook.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed, 0f, 1f, value => freeLook.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
freeLook.m_YAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
freeLook.m_XAxis.m_MaxSpeed = 0;
```

You can just set the values to 0

Answer (score -1):

you can probably remove the component that will probably help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).